# How to Permanently Change CSS Render Locally on Remote Site

Tags: css, google-chrome, local-storage

Sometimes it would be useful to permanently change how someone else's site renders in my browser because I don't like the way the UI is set up (for instance, sometimes certain `divs` cover up content I want to access if I hover over them).

[Here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/devtools-release-notes#overrides) Google had announced "local overrides" in Chrome (and if I am interpreting what this is correctly, this is essentially what I want). Unfortunately, this feature was supposed to be released in Chrome 64, but has not been implemented yet. Is there another way I can have persistent "local overrides" on specific pages' stylesheets?

Comment: If you like the Chrome implementation, you could run the Canary build: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html (just checked and it's enabled for me)

Comment: I am running Canary now, but is there a solution that doesn't have the possibility of crashing on me?

Comment: In my experience, Canary is quite stable (and actually, I just checked and 65 is now in beta, which should be even more stable). The next best option might be an extension to do this for you; a quick search turned up this one: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en .